# display images sequence using videofilereader

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I try to develop a code (as follow) to display a video from file call 'image' that contain jpeg image frames. However its display and stop until the last frame, which mean the display window is blinking. How can I create a loop so it will display the frame 1-by-1 smoothly?

```
file = dir('image/*.jpg');
Numfile = size(file,1);
for I=1:Numfile
 vidRead = vision.VideoFileReader(Files(I).name);
vidPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;
 while ~isDone(vidRead)
  vidFrame = step(vidRead);
  step(vidPlayer, vidFrame);
 end
end
```

Comment: Move `imshow` into the for loop.

Comment: @hbaderts Thank you. But it doesn't play smoothly. How can I make it run smoothly? I mean without stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file = dir('image/*.jpg');
Numfile = size(file,1);
vidPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;
for I=1:Numfile
  vidFrame = imread(file(I).name);
  step(vidPlayer, vidFrame);
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Dima, but how can I make it to play at normal speed?

Comment: `vision.VideoPlayer` knows nothing of "normal speed". It just renders the frames as fast as it can. If you want to slow down the playback, you can put a `pause` statement before `step`.